# Stationary distribution of balls in a box

Tags: probability

Consider $100$ unit radius balls in a 2d upright square box with is $1000$ by $1000$. Let us say they each start at a random position at unit speed with a random direction.  Each weighs $1$ kilogram and is subject to gravity. The balls are perfectly elastic.

What can we say about the stationary distribution of the positions of these balls?  Is this something that is already known?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I suggest you read up about the kinetic theory of gases and Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics, which provide answers to this question.

This question might be more appropriate for Physics SE.

Comment: Do you know a reference by any chance?

Comment: Here are two: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution, http://pirila.fi/energy/kuvat/barometric_derivation.pdf. The theory would need some adjustment to cover the 2-dimensional case.